Not Getting the Image Into Firebase Push Notification IOS For Flutter?
I'm implementing push notifications in my Flutter app using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). Everything works well, and I can receive text-based notifications on both Android and iOS. However, I cannot get the image to display in the notification on iOS, even though it works fine on Android.

Here see if there's anything useful here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image

Here are some steps and solutions to help resolve this:
Notification payload update:
Make sure your FCM payload includes the mutable-content key set to true. This is required for media attachments on iOS.
{
  "to": "<device_token>",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Title",
    "body": "Body",
    "mutable_content": true,
    "image": "https://example.com/image.png"
  },
  "data": {
    "image": "https://example.com/image.png"
  }
}

Service Extension:
On iOS, we need a Notification Service Extension to handle rich media, if not setup already follow Firebase iOS Rich Media Setup step-by-step instructions.
iOS 10+ Requirement:
Images in notifications only work on iOS 10 or later, so make sure your app's Info.plist and deployment target.

I am directing sending from firebase messaging, there we don't needed to add these payloads manually

@RakeshSaini Have you already done with Notification Service Extension ? if not then try configuring it.
